# Difference between domain and dominion

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can anybody give me more examples on how to use these words? I know for sure than you should not use dominion as domain for the Internet but apart from that sight difference both words seem to be synonyms to me.

```
and Death shall have no Dominion by Dylan Thomas
```

**UPDATE**

to [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/dominion) as a governed area they have the same meaning? So I guess "The domain of the Roman Empire" or  "The dominion of the Roman Empire" are both legal. Am I right?

Comment: What did the Dictionary say?

Comment: For one thing, dominion is applicable in terms of a possessive i.e. *he has dominion over them*, whereas domain cannot be applied as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An expansion of kolossus' comment]

Both *domain* and *dominion* have multiple related meanings.

ODO defines *[domaine](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/domain?q=domain)* as both

> An area of territory owned or controlled by a ruler or government: *the southwestern French domains of the Plantagenets*
>
> and
>
> A specified sphere of activity or knowledge: *the expanding domain of psychology*

In both cases, it is the subject of control by a ruler, or under the jurisdiction of someone or something.

*[Dominion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dominion)* is defined by the same source as

> Sovereignty; control: *man’s attempt to establish dominion over nature*
>
> and
>
> (usually dominions) The territory of a sovereign or government: *the Angevin dominions*

While both can refer to the territory over which one has control, *dominion* also refers to the act or process control itself. As such it seems to have a slightly more active connotation, suggesting strength or even force,not just possession.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if you Google them that *[dominion](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dominion&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdominion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdominion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDominion%3B%2Cc0)* is falling out of use and was more popular in antiquity. One plausible explanation for that could be that it was already used in Old French, literally as *dominion*. Whereas, *[domain](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=domain&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdomain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdomain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDomain%3B%2Cc0)* is much more commonly used today. Domain evolved from the Old French word *demaine* and was slowly adopted into Latin. Finally, today it is derived from the Latin word *domanium*.

Answer (score 1):

- if you're talking about a field of study or an area of knowledge, that's a *domain*, not a *dominion* (e.g. *I specialise in the domain of theoretical physics*). This is also probably where the computing/Internet usage of the term *domain* came from.
- *domain* is also used in magnetism and in maths - in neither case can you use *dominion*
- *dominion* (but not *domain*) is used when talking about having control/power/command over something (eg. *to establish dominion over nature*)

While both words originate from the same Latin root of *dominus* (a lord, master), *dominion* is closer related in meaning to a third similar word, *to dominate*, while *domain* developed separately, originally denoting the land or property of a lord/master. As such, *domain* concerns area/territory, while *dominion* concerns having control over something - and yes, that results in some overlap.

However, only in one case is there a possible overlap between *domain* and *dominion*, and that is when we're talking about a territory or land that is controlled by some ruler or government. When to use which in this case is beyond me, though there are particular areas/territories that are generally referred to as one or the other.

Also, note that some countries in the British Commonwealth used to be known as *Dominions* - eg. *the Dominion of Canada*. As this was a proper noun, *Domain of Canada* would not be an acceptable synonym here.